# How to bypass FormClosing event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, formclosing

I have the following code:

```
private void form1_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide(); 
}
```

I want a button that closes the form, without triggering this event. How do I do this?

The code for the button:

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit(); 
}
```

I want the above button to close the form and not hide it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
//unsubscribe the mean "don't let me close" handler
this.FormClosing -= form1_closing; 
//close form
this.Close();
```

Another option would be to make a boolean field "shouldIReallyClose".  Default it to false.  When you really want to close the form set it to true.  Change the event handler to check that boolean before canceling the event.

Comment: I am not following you...this is what i have:         private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Closing -= form1_closing;   
            this.Close(); 
        }

Comment: that is the button that will close the form

Comment: Really fixed now (and verified with a real compiler).  Need to use the `FormClosing` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(!boolTrackingButtonPressed)
    {
       base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to prevent from closing most of the time, but have a method that lets him actually close it.  Letting it be actually closed all of the time solves this problem, but un-solves another.

Comment: oh, took a second try - probably not better than other solution but leaving it unless it's plain wrong.